# How to set/save back-end access time into tables instead of front end

Tags: datetime, ms-access, backend, compatibility

I split an access database into backend and frontend. When a user whose workstation date and time is not set or is not compatible with backend database. When a record is entered by user in table using front end access forms, the time that of front end is save into back end tables whereas in table field =now() is set as default value in access backend.

How to set/save back-end access time into tables instead of front end.

Answer (score 0):

> When a user whose workstation date and time is not set or is not
>   compatible with backend database.

1. The time - if within the range of DateTime - will always be
   compatible.
2. The workstation must be set to the current time. This
   has been a non-issue since Windows 95 and, if failing, can easily be corrected by
   any IT techie.